# How to upload a http file to Hostsite(DreamHost)

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, http

How do i upload a http file to any hosting sites? Preferably Dreamhost.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by an http file? If you simply want to transfer files back and forth between your web server I would recommend using FTP (file transfer protocol).

I would also highly recommend [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) as an FTP client. For more information on connecting via FTP check out this DreamHost wiki article: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/FTP

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Uploading_your_site

This tells you how to upload your website to dreamhost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FTP, please just download FIlezilla free from google and then upload it to your root folder. Just simple like that. :)